# ASP.net Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement - cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: asp.net

Currently doing a project and I am having a serious problem with some code. I keep getting the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() and i have searched all over the internet to find the solution. I have inserted [] in certain catagories and still produces the same error.

All I am doing is creating a page where people can input data for certain catagories, in which once added, it will be updated to the access database. I had this working on an earlier version but ever since i added more characters, it has come with this error.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="addcar.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.addcar" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
       <p>
        <br />
        CarName<asp:TextBox ID="tb_CarName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
      <p>
        <br />
        Year<asp:TextBox ID="tb_Year" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
      <p>
        <br />
        EngineSize<asp:TextBox ID="tb_EngineSize" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
      <p>
        <br />
        BHP<asp:TextBox ID="tb_BHP" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
      <p>
        <br />
        Origin<asp:TextBox ID="tb_Origin" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
      <p>
        <br />
        Description<asp:TextBox ID="tb_Description" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
       <p>
        <br />
        Pictures<asp:TextBox ID="tb_Pictures" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </p>
         <p>
             <asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" Text="Add Car Details" />
    </p>
   </asp:Content>
```

**Followed by the button code which is:**

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class addcar
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
    Protected Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
        Dim oleDbConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CarsConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Dim SqlString As String = "Insert into Table1(CarName,Year,EngineSize,BHP,Origin,Description,Pictures) Values (@f1,@f2,@f3,@f4,@f5,@f6,@f7)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SqlString, oleDbConn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", tb_CarName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f2", tb_Year.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f3", tb_EngineSize.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f4", tb_BHP.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f5", tb_Origin.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f6", tb_Description.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f7", tb_Pictures.Text)
        oleDbConn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Response.Redirect("confirmation.aspx")


    End Sub

End Class
```

Help? What am I doing wrong?

**Error is as follows:**

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: The markup (`.aspx`) is not needed here. What **is** needed is the error message. And perhaps examples of the categories that cause the issue and those that do not. The database definition of `Table1` can also help us help you.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. Error is as follows. When I revert back to my old settings it still comes with the same error now :(

Comment: Error is as follows http://i40.tinypic.com/5lozm1.png

Comment: I suggest you check that `INSERT` statement then. The error says there is a syntax error there. Try running the same in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio). Also - **you have the text of the error** don't post an image of it.

Comment: Hi, Text version of the picture is here http://pastebin.com/ywKHHmUZ. I am a complete newbie to all this asp.net (uni project) and cant get my head around this error.

Comment: I have checked the insert tag, "insert into table1" which is what my database is called. Again, this has not been modified in any way and was working before, but somehow its all gone horribly wrong

Comment: The error tells you that there is a syntax error in your SQL - the INSERT statement is rejected by SQL Server (or whatever database you are using) as invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Year` is a reserved keyword in access / Jet.
You need to encapsulate it with square brackets.

```
Dim SqlString As String = "Insert into Table1(CarName, [Year],EngineSize,BHP,Origin,Description,Pictures) Values (@f1,@f2,@f3,@f4,@f5,@f6,@f7)"
```

You can check every reserved keyword in the jet engine here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738

Comment: Then please be so kind and mark this as an answer by clicking on the checked symbol left to my answer